# Angular path with hyphen character not allowed

Tags: angularjs

When I use the following:

```
$location.path('/product/ninja-game');  //No error in console but the path isn't changed
```

The path is not changed but it works when I use following:

```
$location.path('/product/ninja_game');
```

Is there anything specific to hyphen/dash character in angularjs path. I couldn't find anything specific in the docs.

Code:

```
$scope.buildProductDetails = function(product) {
        var tempTitle = product.title.toLowerCase();
        tempTitle = tempTitle.replace(/adobe/g, "").trim();
        tempTitle = tempTitle.replace(/\s+/g, '-'); //replacing space with hyphen
        console.log(tempTitle);
        $location.path('/product/' + tempTitle);
}
```

Comment: Hyphen/dash should not be a problem. I think the problem lies somewhere else. Can you post more code? Especially the part where you call this `$location.path`?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov add the code in above question description

Comment: can you hardcode the path like `$location.path('/product/ninja-game');` and check just to see whether the problem in the variable `tempTitle`?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov pls post this as answer. I messed up with the variable. worked with hardcoded string like u said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyphen/dash should not be a problem

Probably the problem is in the variable `tempTitle`.

Hardcode the path like `$location.path('/product/ninja-game');` and check just to see whether the problem in the variable `tempTitle`.